# Has anyone used PhoneGap to make 2D games for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, javascript, html5, html-canvas

I love simple casual games. I've been riding the bus a lot recently and so simple, no-brainer games are great fun and well worth the small price I pay on the App Store.

It got me thinking... I know HTML5, CSS3 and JS very well. I looked into [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) and it looks like it's something I could use for making apps for the iPhone.

The games I've been fleshing out myself are very simple 2D affairs. Fun, simple and high quality. That's what I'm after with my games... I also make music and my friend is an digital illustrator so together we have all the media covered.

Does any one make 2D games for the iPhone using PhoneGap?

I'm presuming that because I want to code in JS and use the HTML5 Canvas tag, that PhoneGap does nothing more than provide me a wrapper with a WebKit view?

I know it won't be as fast as using native... But is using PhoneGap a viable option?

Comment: Asking if somebody has used PhoneGap is not a suitable question for this site. Also if a technology is viable is entirely subjective. Check out the FAQ: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have an Apple Developer account, then there is no way to deploying your app into any iOS device for testing. So you've no other go but to accept using emulators. PhoneGap does pretty well when it comes to emulation as far as I know.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question though.